# RISC architecture explained in book "computer organization and design"

Tags: assembly

Concerning book "computer organization and design" by Patterson, Hessney: I do not understand if the assembly code in book is a simpliefied MIPS R2000 or another MIPS chip. When I search more exercises on the internet, I always find exercises with a wider istruction set than the one in reference data attached to the book.

On IRC, a person said that it could be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLX

Do you agree?

Comment: I don't have my copy of the book handy, but IIRC, that's described in some of the early bits of the book - preface or introduction or something... Could be one of the appendices, though, as well...

Comment: Yeah I searched into these sections you mentioned, but I did not find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a PDF version of the 4th edition online - this is described in chapter 1 (page 39 in the PDF, labelled page 10 in the paper edition - if you've got a different edition, it may be slightly off). It's a subset of MIPS64, and they give a table of the instructions they use...

Comment: Now it's time to me to find a good resource for exercises. I don't like much using SPIM